mgcv predict.gam in R version 4 gives error, in R version 3, no error
In R version 3.6.3, my predict.gam function gives a result. When I use R 4.x, I get errors for some types of predict, but not others:

library(gam)
library(dplyr)


gm1 <- predCol ~ s(VCF_nontree) + s(VCF_nonvegt) + s(VCF_treecov) + 
  s(CCI_URBAN) + s(GPW_POP)

gm2 <- predCol ~ offset(offset) + s(ACC) + s(EARS) + s(MAT) + s(PTA) + 
  s(SLP) + s(SOC) + s(TWI)


set.seed(42)
c2 <- data.frame(
  predCol = abs(rnorm(677072, 0.022, 0.03)),
  VCF_nontree = rnorm(677072, 6533, 16.3),
  VCF_nonvegt =rnorm(677072, 15.9, 12.03),
  VCF_treecov = rnorm(677072, 18.1, 18.3),
  CCI_URBAN = rnorm(677072, 0.00412, 0.013), 
  GPW_POP = rnorm(677072, 2.23, 1.28), 
  offset = rep(NA, 677072), 
  ACC = rnorm(677072, 612.6, 456.5), 
  EARS = rnorm(677072, 731.88, 291.4), 
  MAT = rnorm(677072, 22.69, 2.56), 
  PTA = rnorm(677072, 124.13, 307.9), 
  SLP = rnorm(677072, 2.41, 3.71), 
  SOC = rnorm(677072, 0.609, 0.33), 
  TWI = rnorm(677072, 118.2, 15.35)
)

fitModel1.1       <- gam::gam(gm1,
                              data = c2,
                              family = quasibinomial)
c2$offset  <- as.numeric(predict(fitModel1.1,
                                        type = "link"))

fitModel1         <- gam::gam(gm2,
                              data = c2,
                              family=quasibinomial)
fm1               <- predict(fitModel1,
                             se.fit = TRUE,
                             type = "response")



fm1 gives a result in R3.6.3 but not in R4.3.2
R4 throws this error:
Error in NextMethod("predict") : no method to invoke
in R4: gam_1.22-2
in R3: gam_1.20
I am very interested in getting a result in R4.

Works fine for me on examples in mgcv::gam. Make it reproducible!

yeah, the examples in mgcv worked for me too. But the error still exists with my data, and I would feel self conscious pasting the output of dput of a dataframe 301499 x 37. If I can create a reprex, you'll be the first to know.

Which mgcv version are you using with R 3.6.3? At least show the model formula.

For making a self contained small example you can also make up some data. How else should we know why it's failing. Even the package maintainer wouldn't accept this I guess.

the question is closed, but I will a) include the model code (sorry) and b) describe the behaviour of what fixed the issue. The output of
covariate$offset  <- predict(fitModel1.1, type = "link")
was fed into the second gam, which then could not predict. It turns out the covariate$offset was being returned as a 1-d array, which needed to be set to as.numeric() before the second predict would work.
For some reason this is not/was not an issue in R/3.6.3, which worked fine, but is an issue in R/4.

@we the question has been reopened; you can post to Your Answer below.

better discussion of this question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78695116/predict-gam-behaviour-gives-error-in-r4-but-works-in-r3-full-reprex-included?noredirect=1#comment138772081_78695116
