predict.gam behaviour gives error in R4 but works in R3. full reprex included
In R version 3.6.3, my predict.gam function gives a result. When I use R 4.x, I get errors for some types of predict, but not others.
My goal is to be able to use this code in R4.
library(gam)


gm1 <- predCol ~ s(VCF_nontree) + s(VCF_nonvegt) + s(VCF_treecov) + 
  s(CCI_URBAN) + s(GPW_POP)

gm2 <- predCol ~ offset(offset) + s(ACC) + s(EARS) + s(MAT) + s(PTA) + 
  s(SLP) + s(SOC) + s(TWI)


set.seed(42)
c2 <- data.frame(
  predCol = abs(rnorm(677072, 0.022, 0.03)),
  VCF_nontree = rnorm(677072, 6533, 16.3),
  VCF_nonvegt =rnorm(677072, 15.9, 12.03),
  VCF_treecov = rnorm(677072, 18.1, 18.3),
  CCI_URBAN = rnorm(677072, 0.00412, 0.013), 
  GPW_POP = rnorm(677072, 2.23, 1.28), 
  offset = rep(NA, 677072), 
  ACC = rnorm(677072, 612.6, 456.5), 
  EARS = rnorm(677072, 731.88, 291.4), 
  MAT = rnorm(677072, 22.69, 2.56), 
  PTA = rnorm(677072, 124.13, 307.9), 
  SLP = rnorm(677072, 2.41, 3.71), 
  SOC = rnorm(677072, 0.609, 0.33), 
  TWI = rnorm(677072, 118.2, 15.35)
)

fitModel1.1       <- gam::gam(gm1,
                              data = c2,
                              family = quasibinomial)
c2$offset  <- as.numeric(predict(fitModel1.1,
                                        type = "link"))

fitModel1         <- gam::gam(gm2,
                              data = c2,
                              family=quasibinomial)
fm1               <- predict(fitModel1,
                             se.fit = TRUE,
                             type = "response")

in R3 I get a result, in R4 I get this error:
Error in NextMethod("predict") : no method to invoke

R3, gam 1.20, R4 gam 1.22-2
in R4, this call to predict works:
fm2               <- predict(fitModel1,
                             se.fit = TRUE,
                             type = "link")


Confirmed w/ gam 1.22-3 R 4.4.1 on Linux.

if you set se.fit = FALSE, then it works. Seems like a problem with se.fit? Anyone know a workaround?

mgcv::gam works fine for me. Might be worth pinging the gam maintainer.

Looks like it's because predict.Gam calls predict.Gam directly in the switch statement. If it just called predict() with the updated arguments (to get SEs on the link scale first) then everything works.

@GavinSimpson I don't think I understand your answer. Do you know a way I can call predict() explicitly to make it work?

@jay.sf yes, I can also make mgcv::gam work, but the wall time is much higher, and for reproducibility I would prefer gam::gam. In my production code, I call the gam() function many times iteratively, and the time overhead for mgcv::gam is too high compared to gam::gam for my computing hardware. Maybe there is a way to speed up mgcv::gam. So far mgcv::bam is not working for me.

@weneedaMat.Stat. well, if you know how to edit code in a namespace (fixInNamespace()) you could find the switch() statement and fix the issue. You can also email Trevor with a bug report and point to the specific problem. You can't fix this yourself (except temporarily with fixInNamespace()) but do you need standard errors as it works with se.fit = FALSE

Is mgcv::gam() really slower than gam::gam() if you set fx = TRUE on each smooth (in the mgcv version) so that you're fitting comparable models?

I don't know how to format this nicely:
fitModel1 <- gam::gam(gm2, data = c2, family = quasibinomial)
fitModel1mgcv <- mgcv::gam(gm2, data = c2, family = quasibinomial, fx = TRUE)
mb <- microbenchmark(
"gam::gam" = gam::gam(gm2, data = c2, family = quasibinomial),
"mgcv::gam" = mgcv::gam(gm2, data = c2, family = quasibinomial, fx = TRUE),
times = 3)
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval gam::gam  25.48137  25.51025  28.30767  25.53912  29.72081  33.90251     3 mgcv::gam 426.72876 432.04498 474.16970 437.36121 497.89018 558.41914     3

That looks pretty off. Why don't you write the game maintainer an email, you can link this question.

The fx = TRUE needs to go on each smooth, not as an argument to gam(). You can just edit your Question, rather than trying to format output in a comment.

update
the package maintainer has fixed the issue, and new version of gam on cran no longer need a workaround, and work as designed!
Following the advice of @GavinSimpson, I made a workaround: a custom predict.gam() function that can be called in an Rscript using
 source("custom_predict_Gam.R") I save the below script in my working directory, then in R 4, use source(), then call the function like this:
fm1               <- custom_predict_Gam(fitModel1,
                                        se.fit = TRUE,
                                        type = "response")

and get results identical to those from R 3.
Thanks for everyone's input. This has made me happy. gam::happy...
On the off chance that this is useful to anyone else, here is the function that I save as custom_predict_Gam.R:

# custom_predict_Gam.R

# this file replaces the predict.gam on line 18 with predict. The reason is because predict.gam is broken in R 4.



custom_predict_Gam <- function (object, newdata, type = c("link", "response", "terms"), 
                                dispersion = NULL, se.fit = FALSE, na.action = na.pass, terms = labels(object), 
                                ...) 
{
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (missing(newdata)) {
    if (inherits(object, "Gam") && !is.null(object$smooth)) {
      if (se.fit) 
        switch(type, 
               response = {
                 out <- predict(object, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE, ...)
                 famob <- family(object)
                 out$se.fit <- drop(out$se.fit * abs(famob$mu.eta(out$fit)))
                 out$fit <- fitted(object)
                 out
               }, 
               link = {
                 out <- NextMethod("predict")
                 out$fit <- object$additive.predictors
                 TS <- out$residual.scale^2
                 TT <- ncol(object$var)
                 out$se.fit <- sqrt(out$se.fit^2 + TS * object$var %*% 
                                      rep(1, TT))
                 out
               }, 
               terms = {
                 out <- NextMethod("predict")
                 TT <- dimnames(s <- object$smooth)[[2]]
                 TT = intersect(terms, TT)
                 out$fit[, TT] <- out$fit[, TT] + s[, TT]
                 TS <- out$residual.scale^2
                 out$se.fit[, TT] <- sqrt(out$se.fit[, TT]^2 + 
                                            TS * object$var[, TT])
                 out
               })
      else switch(type, 
                  terms = {
                    out <- NextMethod("predict")
                    TT <- dimnames(s <- object$smooth)[[2]]
                    TT = intersect(terms, TT)
                    out[, TT] <- out[, TT] + s[, TT]
                    out
                  }, 
                  link = object$additive.predictors, 
                  response = object$fitted)
    }
    else {
      if (inherits(object, "Gam")) {
        if (type == "link" && !se.fit) 
          object$additive.predictors
        else NextMethod("predict")
      }
      else UseMethod("predict")
    }
  }
  else newdata.predict.Gam(object, newdata, type, dispersion, 
                           se.fit, na.action, terms, ...)
}



I forgot to add, I also emailed the gam package maintainer


I wonder if you have received a reply from the maintainer yet?

yes! I just edited the answer to include that the maintainer has fixed it! onwards with the science! Thanks @jay.sf
